# Import Error in Postgis: AddGeometryColumn does not exist

Tags: postgis

```
Importing with configuration: ind_adm2, public, geom, C:\Program Files\OpenGeo\OpenGeo Suite\webapps\geoserver\india map\IND_adm2, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
Shapefile type: Polygon
PostGIS type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
Failed SQL begins: "SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO UTF8;
SET STANDARD_CONFORMING_STRINGS TO ON;
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "public"."ind_adm2" (gid serial,
"id_0" int4,
"iso" varchar(3),
"name_0" varchar(75),
"id_1" int4,
"name_1" varchar(75),
"id_2" int4,
"name_2" varchar(75),
"nl_name_2""
Failed in pgui_exec(): ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 17: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','ind_adm2','geom','0','MUL...
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Shapefile import failed.
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange?  Unfortunately, it is not clear what your precise question is so would you be able to expand upon it with more text explanation, please?

Answer (score 11):

Looks like your postgis installation is not complete. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132649/osm2pgsql-function-addgeometrycolumn-doesnt-exist for a similar situation.

You might refer to the tutorials at http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/.

If you are running postgis 2.0, some commands may have beeen renamed.