# Error 2: Importing Shapefile to QGIS DB Manager Failure || PostGIS || PgAdmin

Tags: qgis, postgis, import, pgadmin-4, dbmanager

I am new to PostgreSQL, PostGIS, and pgAdmin. I am trying to import a shapefile through the DB Manager (PostGIS --> my specific database) in QGIS. I keep getting an Error 2 message indicating that my shapefile cannot be uploaded. I have already successfully completed the PostGIS connection in QGIS. Additionally, I had already successfully created the extension for PostGIS in pgAdmin (CREATE EXTENSION postgis;). I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is an image of my error:

[image: Error 2 Failure]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question so that the error message is in the body of the Question as text (images are not legible on all devices, and hide the Question (and Answer) from others who may encounter the same error).

Comment: Take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63982/import-error-in-postgis-addgeometrycolumn-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, just install the extensions listed in your default "postgres" database in the extensions provided under your newly created database.
For example, I created a database called "princedb". Right click on the Extensions under princedb, click on create -> Extension. Install fuzzystrmatch, postgis, postgis_tiger_geocoder, postgis_toplogy extensions. Refresh your database on pgAdmin and QGIS. Try uploading your shapefiles. It should work fine.